# Resulting pressure of batteries in series

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, batteries

Hi everyone we are working on a battery project and have the following question. What is the influence of stacking battery cells next to each other in a battery module on the resulting pressure exerted on the two walls clamping the cells?

The cells will want to expand when charging but are restricted by fixed walls, this will generate pressure. At first glance, it seems obvious that the resulting pressure will be $P_{module} = n \cdot P_{cell}$, but after some discussions with my colleagues, we see that different interpretations of the representation of the battery will lead to different results.

(in the picture it might look like the cell has halved in size, but the cells are all identical)

Thank you for the help!

[image: fixing one cell]

[image: fixing two cells]